# Spring JPA Crud Repository save() not updating entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In my code i am trying to update my entity but data is not getting saved in db.
checked logs there is no exception as well.
Also tried `@Transaction` annotation but it doesn't work.

**Method for save call**

```
public void uploadBill(Long quoteId, MultipartFile multiPartFile) {
    try {
        ServiceQuote serviceQuote = serviceQuoteRepository.findOne(quoteId);

        String extension = "";
        if (multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
            extension = multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename().substring(
                    multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf("."),
                    multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename().length());
        }
        String filename = SERVICING_BILL_FILE_PREFIX
                + serviceQuote.getReferenceNo() + extension;
        filename = AmazonS3Util.uploadBill(multiPartFile, filename);

        serviceQuote.setBillPath(filename);
        serviceQuoteRepository.save(serviceQuote);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here serviceQuoteRepository is JPA crud repositorty

```
@Repository
public interface ServiceQuoteRepository extends CrudRepository<ServiceQuote, Long> {}
```

Please suggest what could be possible fix.

Comment: Can you add this lines to your application.properties and paste the output after saving to your question? "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace"

Comment: Are you sure the entity is not saved (double check it with a data base tool, make sure the view was refreshed)?

Comment: @Journeycorner I have all the props in application.properties. I checked many times entity not getting saved with the updated values.

Comment: I had a similar issue, which I solve dby adding a TransactionManager bean definition. Previously I did not have one (or Spring provided one that did not fit). This is vary vague, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @ C-Otto how can I add TransactionManager bean definition? I mean do I need to change in repository ?

Comment: can you add your application.yml I donot see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue related to crud repository. Actually after upload method another service was updating the entity with null bill path at the same time so I was seeing the null column always. Figured out after debugging the issue for few hours.